# Can a Cameroon citizen with an expired passport and an ILR travel?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, cameroonian-citizens

I have a ILR in the UK, known as settled. My Cameroon passport is expired.
I have applied for a new passport, but haven’t got it yet. I have the récépissé of the passport.

Can I travel to Paris for a week with my ILR and the Récépissé of my passport?

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

Even if you have residency in the UK, as a Cameroonian citizen you'll need a valid Schengen visa to visit Paris, and for that you need a passport.

In the longer term, if you've held ILR for more than a year you might be eligible to become a British citizen and get a UK passport, which would save a lot of visa troubles in the future.

Answer (score 3):

No,  you cannot cross the Schengen external border without a valid travel document. The only exception to this is EU/EEA citizens carrying national ID cards.

For a Cameroon passport you'll *also* need a visa.